# How to add filter criteria from child object attributes

Tags: soql

`Parent__c` has many `Child__c`

`Child__c` is defined by boolean attribute `Checkbox__c`.

How do I select all Parents where `Child__c.Checkbox__c = true`?

The following doesn't work:

```
Parent__c[] parents = [SELECT Id FROM Parent__c WHERE Child__r.Checkbox__c = true];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to query the children records (nested query) and check against the size of the list:

`Parent__c[] parents = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Children__r WHERE Checkbox__c = true) FROM Parent__c]` where Children__r is your child relationship name on the Parent lookup.

Then you need to go through the list and work out which parent has children with checkbox = true:

```
Parent__c[] parentsMatchCriteria = new List <Parent__c> ();

for (Parent__c parent : parents)
{
    if (parent.Children__r.size() > 0)
    {
        // this parent has children with checkbox__c = true, add it to a list
        parentsMatchCriteria.add(parent);
    }
}
// work with the list - parentsMatchCriteria
```

Alternatively, you can start from the children:

`Child__c[] children = [SELECT Parent__r.Id, Parent__r.CustomField__c FROM Child__c WHERE Checkbox__c = true]`

then iterate through that list and build up the list of parents:

```
Parent__c[] parentsList = new List <Parent__c> ();

for (Child__c child : children)
{
    Parent__c parent = new Parent__c (Id = child.Parent__r.Id);
    parent.CustomField__c = child.Parent__r.CustomField__c;
    // add the parent sObject instance to the list
    parentsList.add(parent);
}
// work with the list - parentsList
```